# javascript between jade file failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

My below code broken

```
span 
    a.active(href="#{code}")
    - myArr.forEach(entry){
      if(entry.code == code){
        #{entry.ItemName}  
      }
    }
```

My expected result is

```
<span><a href="John">John James</a></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing javascript to be executed by Jade with output code. Use this:

```
span 
  a.active(href = code)
    each entry in myArr
      if entry.code == code
        = entry.ItemName
```

Changes:

- use [`each...in`](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/)
- use [`tag = variable`](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/) for interpolation when possible, not `#{variable}`
- Jade doesn't have brackets, it's indentation based
- [`if`](http://jade-lang.com/reference/conditionals/) doesn't need parens

Comment: wow must it be indented that way? is the indent for js in jade means scope? because you don't have the `{` anymore.

Comment: #{var} is no good? why? It's how you bind your js variable no?

Comment: @MaySun [Interpolation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/), `#{...}`, only has meaning inside of [plain text](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/) and attribute values. On a line of its own, you can use it by adding a pipe, `|`, at the start of the line. Or, as shown, you can switch to [buffered code](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/) using an `=`.